# Sendgrid Inbound Web Hook using Web API C Sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sendgrid, stronggrid

I am trying to parse emails coming in from send grid using the web hook feature but just get the below error...

> "An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: W. Path '', line 1, position 6.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException","StackTrace":"   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberCharIntoBuffer(Char currentChar, Int32 charPos)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberIntoBuffer()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonConverter[] converters)\r\n   at StrongGrid.WebhookParser.ParseWebhookEvents(String requestBody) in C:\projects\stronggrid\Source\StrongGrid\WebhookParser.cs:line 48\r\n   at WebAPI_InboundMail.Controllers.HomeController.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Dev\Baxter Personnel\Projects\Comms\WebAPI_InboundMail\WebAPI_InboundMail\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 23\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

Here is my code, any help be great...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        var requestBody = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var parser = new WebhookParser();
        var events = parser.ParseWebhookEvents(requestBody);

        bool status = true;
        var response = status == true? new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) : new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        return Ok("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message (which is `Unexpected character encountered while parsing number`), it sounds like the WebhookParser in the StrongGrid library is trying to parse a given value into a number but the value in the Json sent by SendGrid is not numerical.

Can you look at the content of your `requestBody` variable and detect which property is causing the issue? If you post the content of your variable I'll try to help.